# drawcontoursの色について

Tags: c#, opencv

OpenCvSharpにてdrawcontoursを使用して輪郭描画を行っていますが、この時輪郭描画で表示される色についてご質問があります。(出力画像は(8U3C))
この描画される色に黒や黒に近い色を使いたいのですが、例えばColorに渡すScalarの値を(0, 0, 0)とすると線が消失します。((255, 0, 0)の様にすれば表示されます)
透過っぽくもあった為、念の為、Scalarの4番目の要素を(0, 0, 0, 255)の様にしても線が表示されません。
drawcontoursで黒線を表示する為にはどうすればよろしいかご教授願います。

環境はVisual Studio Express 2017 で
OpenCvSharp3 AnyCPU(v4.0.30319)を使用しています。